# 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 Steam Install Issue

Tags: launcher, 64-bit, games, steam

I'm sure many of you know (including me,) that steam runs on 32 bit infrastructure. This is to make steam more readily accessible to many users. I'm sure many of you also know that when you download Ubuntu 16.04 you have to then download some libraries that allow steam to work but for some reason they aren't included in the install.

I researched on the web for a while and learned how to extract the .deb file of Steam. However, I got stuck on the launcher. Whenever I run the launcher it asks me to install some files. When I write in my password of approval, the code says that it can't install the files :(.

Please help me. I'm seriously considering to uninstall ubuntu and install the 12.04 version to my computer which is compatible with steam. or just download steam OS. However if anyone could help me that would be great because I like 16.04 and it's application store thing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the exact text of any prompts or messages you get from the Steam launcher, since without those details your question is a bit vague. What files does it say it's going to install? Are there any other details given?

Comment: I'll get on my computer and paste the code.

Comment: my response is in an answer on this post. I didn't have enough charachters.

Comment: I have 16.04 64bit and no extra packages are required for Steam, all you need is `sudo apt install steam`, if you still have issues, based on this error: "steam-launcher depends on python-apt; however: Package python-apt is not installed." You need to install the package `pyton-apt` run `sudo apt install python-apt`

Comment: Try the [steam-native-runtime](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=steam-native-runtime) package from Arch. I read that it installs the needed libraries that otherwise would not be installed using the [steam-latest](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb) Debian archive.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps mentioned under manual installation on this page https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus and installation did run flawless on 64-bit ubuntu 16.10.

```
sudo apt-get install wget gdebi libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo gdebi steam.deb
```

since I ran it on a virtual machine without proprietary drivers the launch of `steam` did spit out some errors of `swrast not found` but this should solve your installation troubles.

Comment: @XxX___EliteKnight420XxX If this answer solved your issue, you can thank the user by clicking the check mark on the left. Plus, it really helps us out ;)

Comment: In this answer, I added the code for you, links alone are no good. Why did you remove this answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/844713/75060 I did not mean you should remove it, I meant you should improve it, I even told you what to add. All it needed was an edit to make it more substantial and it was fine?